# Fix “UnicodeDecodeError: can't decode byte

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well I have written a code in python2. Usually I use python3 and never had the issue but its not working here. Please help, can't post the code, it's the policy. I hope you would understand as a programmer.

Hope anyone can help.

Comment: If you can't post internal code, reproduce a [MCVE] and post that (anyway you are the CEO according to your profile, so why not change your own policy!

Comment: No, nobody can help without more details. There are a million ways to generate that error, and almost as many questions/answers here on StackOverflow already to help you.

Comment: @JonahGraham There are some policies where you are not allowed to post private data anyways from what i understood, I will try to answer as he mentioned python2 and python3 problem.

Comment: This is like asking someone to investigate a murder and only showing them the bullet wound. You haven't given us enough information to enable us to help you.

Comment: @AdeelSafdar Please don't use bad words for anyone, everyone is here to help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import sys

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Its just a guess as there is no code but if your code used to work in python3 and not in Python2 then this was the only problem I could think of. Try this if it helps. Otherwise its very difficult to recognize the issue.

**NOTE:** I may help you in private too but by looking at the question title bytes error, this code usually will solve the issue, just place it at the top after your imports.

Comment: I simply tried to answer, negative points won't hurt me co called programmers. :D

Comment: This SO community is getting egoistic and cheap day by day.

Comment: Yes true, well it will take me 5 minutes to test this code out, if it solves my problem then I will accept it.

Comment: @AdeelSafdar Take your time and even if does not solves the problem, do contact me, I will try and suggest more solutions. :)

Comment: Yes it solved the issue, the problem was I was used to using Python3 nd now for some others requirements I had to turn to Python2 and used the same techniques which apparently were not recognized by python2, but this code solved it, thanks everyone and especially you. :)

Comment: No problem, we are here to help.